# The information could not be retrieved. Maybe your internet connection is down?

Tags: sync, password

I got this error from Ubuntu One Control Panel
It could be related to:
- I tried (at least) tow times upload 3GB file using web interface without success
- I create copy of one file from-to sahred folder + remove original file + change name of copy to the same name as original (copy; remove; mv)

Screenshots:(unable to publish)

System: Ubuntu 11.04

//edit
I forgot about information that ths file which was copy/remove/rename - was removed from web interface before synchronization (was not synchronized in first time because password for ubuntuone was changed before that) - I mean: 0. I removed this file from web interface, and then copy, paste, rename - and then update password - I know it is little complicated - but right now ubuntu one is not working from my compulter - only web interface is working right now.

Comment: //UPDATE now it is working - it could be relate to restart of my machine - nut it was not first time when I restarted it after issue happen).